# What is the rank of a linear transformation space? $L(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

What does the $\operatorname{rank}(f(T))$ mean exactly, if $f:L(V,W) \to L(V,W)$ and $T \in L(V,W)$, where $L(V,W)$ is the set of all linear transformations between two finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and  $W$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, $f$ is a map assigning to each linear map $T$ a linear map $f(T)$. Therefore, $\operatorname{rank}(f(T))$ is the rank of said linear map $f(T)$: $$\operatorname{rank}(f(T))=\dim\left( f(T)(V)\right)$$

Comment: Are you sure its not the dim R($f(T)$)? Is that just all $T$ it encompasses which would be $L(V,W)$

Comment: In my opinion, if $f$ is a linear map, the rank of $f$ (id est, $\dim (f(L(V,W)))$ or $\dim\operatorname{im} f$) would just be $\operatorname{rank} f$. @BBest